# Git on Windows 10 uses a different key than ssh

Tags: windows-10, ssh, git

I have a config issue with using git on windows. The public key git uses is different than the key ssh uses for the same host. In short,

```
ssh git@somewhere
```

asks for the key password and works fine, while

```
$ git remote -v show
somewhere    ssh://git@somewhere/path/to/repo
$ git push somewhere main
git@somewhere: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

fails as above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in some path configuration which I don't know where to change.

I've investigated what files both `ssh.exe` processes open using procmon. Git's ssh attempts to find a key in `%APPDATA%\SPB_Data\.ssh\` while ssh from the command prompt uses keys from `%userprofile%\.ssh\` (Note: `%userprofile%` is by default your `C:\Users\<username>\`).

Before that, ssh when run from "Git bash" window also would fail to connect.

The `%userprofile%\.ssh\` directory did not have any keys in it. I've copied the key from `%userprofile%\.ssh\` to `%APPDATA%\SPB_Data\.ssh\` and now Git connects fine.